# Тип предложения

Tags: синтаксис

> **После ужина она отказалась от идеи позвонить ему: а вдруг он именно
>   на это и надеялся.**

Скажите, пожалуиста, это два самостоятельных предложения или то, что стоит после двоеточия, это причина, почему она отказалась позвонить ему?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После ужина она отказалась от идеи позвонить ему(почему?): а вдруг он именно на это и надеялся.Второе предложение указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первом.

Comment: Спасибо, @Людмила! Но оно не является СПП причины, нет? нет "потому что", а стоит "а". Что это тогда с синтаксическои точки зрения?

Comment: "А" здесь не союз, это усилительная частица. Это бессоюзное сложное предложение.

Comment: спасибо большое большое! : )